# Why the first is evaluated while the second is not (Sum behaves differently from Integrate)?

Tags: function-construction, replacement

```
RegIntegral[Integrate[e_, {t_, 0, Infinity}]] := 5
RegSum[Sum[e_, {t_, 0, Infinity}]] := 5

RegIntegral[Integrate[Exp[3 x], {x, 0, Infinity}]]
RegSum[Sum[Exp[3 x], {x, 0, Infinity}]]
```

The only difference is in the first case we use sum, in the second case, integral. The tech support said it works as it should, and in the secnd case I get infinite loop.

I think, it is a bug.

Comment: Please write an *informative* title.  Yours says nothing about the content of your question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Note that [`Sum`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Sum) has the attribute [`HoldAll`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/HoldAll), while [`Integrate`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Integrate) does not. This means that the definition of `RegSum` has [`Infinity`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Infinity) and not what [`Infinity`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Infinity) evaluates to. The evaluation of [`Infinity`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Infinity):

```
Infinity //FullForm
```

> DirectedInfinity[1]

Your definition:

```
DownValues[RegSum] //FullForm
```

> List[RuleDelayed[HoldPattern[RegSum[Sum[Pattern[e,Blank[]],List[Pattern[t,Blank[]],0,Infinity]]]],5]]

Note the presence of [`Infinity`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Infinity).

When [`Sum`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Sum) evaluates and realizes that it does not converge, it returns a [`Sum`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Sum) expression where [`Infinity`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Infinity) has been replaced with `DirectedInfinity[1]`:

```
Sum[Exp[3 x], {x, 0, Infinity}] //FullForm
```

> Sum::div: Sum does not converge.

> Sum[Power[E,Times[3,x]],List[x,0,DirectedInfinity[1]]]

This means that your definition, which is expecting [`Infinity`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Infinity) doesn't fire because the upper limit is instead `DirectedInfinity[1]`.

A possible workaround is to use:

```
RegSum[Sum[e_,{t_,0,DirectedInfinity[1]}]]:=5
```

Comment: I absolutely do not understand your explanation, but it works!